# Can an exception be overwritten?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a line like:

```
@hsh.has_key?(foo) ? @hsh[foo][bar] : raise("custom error")
```

That I'd rather write like:

```
@hsh[foo][bar] || raise ("custom error")
```

But the NoMethodError is called instead when @hsh[foo] does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

To save an exception, you need `rescue`, but you don't have that anywhere in your code. `||` just reacts to `nil`.

You might want this:

```
@hsh.fetch(foo, {})[bar] || raise("custom error")
```

Comment: When printf debugging, I often have `raise "Can't find #{bar.inspect}"`, or even `raise "Can't find #{bar.inspect} amongst #{@hsh.fetch(foo).keys.inspect}"`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the simplest change:

```
@hsh[foo][bar] rescue raise ("custom error")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's preferred to avoid triggering exceptions if at all possible, but you can always create an inline block that you can rescue out of:

```
begin
  @hsh[foo][bar]
rescue
  raise ("custom error")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`@hsh[foo]` returns `nil`, which doesn't have a `[]` method. Try this one:

```
@hsh[foo] && @hsh[foo][bar] || raise("custom error")
```